# java - is it possible to implement a custom Map of widgets using Widget class or primitive values?(arrays)

Tags: java, dictionary

given:

```
class Widget {
    Object value;
}

interface WidgetMap {
    void put( Widget key, Widget value );
    Widget get( Widget key );
}
```

... how would I go about implementing `WidgetMap` using only `Widget` objects or primitives?
Without the use of other classes (toolkits, collections, JDK classes ). Primitive arrays would be allowed, but it would be better to do without them.

Comment: if this is homework it must be tagged as such, if it isn't just use the collections

Comment: ... no, but close enough

Comment: How can you implement anything in java without using jdk classes?

Comment: I would think that the source for `HashMap`/`Hashtable` would be a huge inspiration here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a map implemented as a linked list of `WidgetMap`. It doesn't strike me as terribly efficient, or useful, but it should function. I assume you also want a `remove` function, but I'll leave that as an exercise. This also assumes you appropriately override the `Widget.equals` function, though it should be trivial to fix it not to have that requirement.

```
class BadMap implements WidgetMap{

    private WidgetMap next = null;
    private Widget key = null;
    private Widget val = null;

    public void put(Widget _key, Widget _value){
        if(key == null){
            key = _key;
            val = _value;
        }else if(key.equals(_key)){
            val = _value;
        }else if(next != null){
            next.put(_key, _value);
        }else{
            next = new BadMap();
            next.put(_key, _value);
        }
    }

    public Widget get(Widget _key){
        if(key != null && key.equals(_key)){
            return val;
        }else if(next != null){
            return next.get(_key);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

[Working example code.](http://ideone.com/ETrzI)